# non-LVM preseed issue? "no root file system"

Tags: server, preseed

I have a working preseed config file using LVM that I'm trying to adapt to the "regular" approach, but all attempts are failing so far with an error that says "No root file system is defined."  This is for an Ubuntu 18 image being created with Packer on a vSphere 6.5 cluster.  The relevant (partman) part of the preseed looks as follows:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
  myroot :: \
  1000 1000 -1 ext4 \
  $primary{ } \
  $bootable{ } \
  method{ format } \
  format{ } \
  use_filesystem{ } \
  filesystem{ ext4 } \
  mountpont{ / } \
  .
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select myroot

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

I am not using the paravirtual driver for these VMs, and have confirmed that /dev/sda is the correct block device name on the console by switching to a separate virtual terminal when the error pops up.

The Packer command works fine if the above is replaced with this, for LVM, but I'm trying to build a "simple" new image without LVM, `/boot`, swap, etc:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `expert_recipe`.

```
  mountpont{ / } \
```

should be

```
  mountpoint{ / } \
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  The typo is certainly real, so I'll give you the answer, but I can't actually test it to see if it solved the problem since I abandoned this approach in favor of just using the `init_automatically_partition` menuitems instead, and since then have moved on to fighting with subiquity to get an automated install of 20.04 working.